# How to call parent resource output in child module in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws, iaas

I am creating a below

ABC
-- ecs.tf     (gives me cluster id)

Content of ecs.tf:

```
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "first_cluster" {
  name = "firstCluster"
  capacity_providers = ["FARGATE"]
  default_capacity_provider_strategy {
    capacity_provider = "FARGATE"
    base              = 0
    weight            = 1
  }
  setting {
    name  = "containerInsights"
    value = "enabled"
  }
}
output "cluster_id" {
  value = aws_ecs_cluster.first_cluster.id
}
```

Now under ABC folder which is root folder, i have another folder with CHILD folder which has app.tf

[image: ABC/ ├─ CHILD/ │ ├─ app.tf ├─ ecs.tf]

**Question:**
How can i use cluster_id from ecs.tf in CHILD\app.tf ?

app.tf:

- module in this file is already calling different module and one of the input is cluster_id.

This is the challenge, i need to get the cluster_id value from ecs.tf output value from parent folder

My app.tf file contains something like below

```
module "xyz" {
source = "some modudle which needs cluster_id as input"
cluster_id = ??
}
```

Help me with what i need to put for cluster_id

Answer (score 0):

> How can i use cluster_id from ecs.tf in CHILD\app.tf ?

You can't access it directly. Your parent module must pass `cluster_id` as an input argument to your module, e.g.:

```
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "first_cluster" {
  name = "firstCluster"
  capacity_providers = ["FARGATE"]
  default_capacity_provider_strategy {
    capacity_provider = "FARGATE"
    base              = 0
    weight            = 1
  }
  setting {
    name  = "containerInsights"
    value = "enabled"
  }
}

module "child" {
  source = "./CHILD"
  cluster_id = aws_ecs_cluster.first_cluster.id
}
```

Comment: Hi Marcin, 

Thank you for the response. Now in my child, app.tf, how do i call this cluster_id ?

app.tf calls another module which needs cluster_id as input

module "xyz" {
source = "someother module which needs cluster id"
cluster_id = ?? 
}

Can you please help me with what i need to put.

Comment: @Springhills you have to keep passing it down in same way to further sub childs.

Comment: Do you mind throwing snippet of code please
How should the code look like ?

Comment: @Springhills this is new issue thus new question should be asked. Also if my answer help you to overcome the original problem reported, it's acceptance would be appreciated.